# Pydantic как сделать input в BaseModel,если множество валидаторов

Tags: python, json, input, pydantic

Есть pydantic User(basemodel).

Нужно сделать заполнение формы через input, присутствуют валидаторы и рут валидаторы. Прописал

```
User(name=input("")
User(last_name=input("")
```

И так далее. Валидаторы срабатывают только после заполнения всех значений, хотя для каждого значения свой валидатор, либо рут валидатор срабатывает до заполнения формы за которую он отвечает. Далее Basemodel нужно добавить в json список.

Помогите)это дз после второго урока по Пайтону

Comment: Как сейчас быстро обучают питону, второй урок, а уже о педантизме идет речь! Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ваши наработки по этому поводу - в виде кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> после заполнения всех значений

Это ключевой момент. Сначала нужно собрать все значения, а уже потом создавать объект:

```
user_attrs = {}
user_attrs["name"] = input()
user_attrs["last_name"] = input()

user = User(**user_attrs)
```

Либо так:

```
user = User(name=input(), last_name=input())
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь Роман))